# How to execute an Http Request Sampler with each of other samplers

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I would like to execute an Http Request Sampler with each request defined in another request group (Simple Controller) but could not find an appropriate construct to achieve this.

More concrete description:
I'd like to execute LogRequest with each of the Req1, Req2, Req3 ... and I dont want to duplicate the LogRequest.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

**Using Samplers:**

A Sampler will not be executed for each sampler in the group/controller.
There seems to be a workaround using Interleave Controller.

[image]

As the picture shows, for each request the in the InterLeave Controller, the Log Request gets executed. The LoopController here is required to execute the InterLeave controller again and again for all the samplers inside the controller.

**Using Post Processor:**

If I were you, I would try to use a Pre Processor / Post Processor. As you need to log something, You can use a beanshell post processor. It would be simply as shown below.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK Interleave controller choosing samplers randomly right? I need them to be executed in order thats why first options is not suitable for my case, for your second suggestion, i need to make a logging request to the server, I am not trying to log to the jmeter console. @vins by the way is there a way to call a sampler from post processors?

Comment: It is not random. They will be executed in the sequence only. But it will execute only one sampler in the group. That is why we combine that with Loop Controller.

Comment: Post Processor is a good choice. But you can not call a sampler. You need to  make the http call yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve it could be:

1. [Interleave Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Interleave_Controller)
2. [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)

Comment: ,How do you use module controller here?

Comment: Hi @dmitri-t, i need to call samplers in the order they defined, so afaik 1. option not working in this scenario, for the second suggestion, i need to duplicate module controllers this time right? Is there a way to call/execute a sampler from a post processor? If its possible I would prefer that option since it will be encapsulated within an Sampler. Thanks,